# Rendering a bitmap buffer into HTML5 canvas with emscripten

Tags: c++, c, emscripten

I have a small game written ages ago that renders to a virtual framebuffer. On the target platform, i blit the final buffer into a bitmap, and end up with the frame rendered. It's similar to what Wolf3D and other old games do.

Is there a way of rendering my game buffer into HTML5 canvas? I know that emscripten uses SDL, but i don't want to force the usage of WebGL, since it's a simple 2D game.

Answer (score -1):

Emscripten's SDL support translates to canvas, not WebGL.

Comment: But am i forced to use SDL on canvas? Isn't there a different way?

Comment: I am no emscripten expert but my understanding is that they basically implement a shim which translates SDL to canvas, and OpenGL to WebGL. If you want to work directly with canvas (without SDL), do it via normal interop. In my project I am just calling extern javascript functions which do the canvas operation. See https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Interacting-with-code#wiki-calling-javascript-from-cc